# Script to compile kernel from source with 'make xconfig'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, compilation, linux-kernel

I'm trying to automate compiling from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) with a bash script. Originally I was using the ncurses menu but I'd like to move to `xconfig`.

The relevant section of code that is causing me difficulty:

```
echo -e "Extracting kernel source."
tar xf $OUTPUT -C ./$FOLDER || { echo "Error extracting the archive." >&2; exit 1; }
EXTRACTED=$(ls $FOLDER/)
echo -e "    Extracted Folder:\t${FOLDER}/${EXTRACTED}\n"

pushd $FOLDER/linux*

echo -e "Launching \"make xconfig\"."
$SUDO make xconfig 2>/dev/null || { echo "Error running \"make xconfig\"."; exit 1; }
```

When it hits the `make xconfig`, it compiles and a GUI is presented but it is blank. If I test the command directly in the shell (i.e. not through the bash script) the menu populates properly.

I've tried all the things I can think of at the moment, including trying to execute both with `sudo` as well as `su` to no avail.

#### UPDATE

The scripts are now posted on github. I thought I'd update this post with a reference for anyone else to use. Enjoy!

[Linux Kernel Utilities](https://github.com/mtompkins/linux-kernel-utilities)

Comment: Why are you doing `sudo` when invoking `make xconfig`? You should execute it as regular user. Also, try to add `#!/bin/bash` (not `sh`) at the first line of your script. Also, it seems like you forgot to do `popd` in the end.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment Sam. Unfortunately it seems I've not been clear. This is only a snippet of the full code. I've shown the part relevant to the launching of xconfig. Sudo and su were tried to confirm it wasn't an issue with a given user / aliases / paths, etc.

Comment: So please try to minimize your script to the only code which causes problem. In other words, provide us with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), so we can actually try your script (w/o any modifications needed) on our machines and see where is the problem. Thanks.

Comment: While nice in theory, a script that references kernel compilation has a battery of dependencies that are necessary so in my view SSCCE is not relevant. That said, however, I will provide a simply script that will reproduce the condition assuming those dependencies are preexisting.

Comment: What do you mean "blank" exactly? Does running `make xconfig </dev/null` manually work correctly? What *else* is your script doing *before* this bit?

Comment: I just hope you are doing this for fun and not planning to use this script in some production environment or something.

Comment: @Borg in production I use a .config file and the entire process works as expected. This was more for amusement, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a hunch, I tried on a different linux machine and the results worked as expected. Then the information was shared that the dev machine has some known X issues (lovely).

I think the credit here goes to @Sam to force me to try and reproduce outside of my script - which although not what was done did inspire an alternate idea.

Comment: I noticed it happens quite often. I mean, sometimes you just need to get rid of all details from your app/script, one by one, and try to leave only the code that really causes the problem. After doing that, root cause (and therefore the solution) comes up very quickly. So before asking something, try to isolate the problem by yourself (in one way or another).

Comment: Sam I think you've made some unfair assumptions, specifically the "before asking something". You have no perspective as to what efforts I may have gone through before posting a query to the community. If you rather not be a part of an area of exchange such as stackoverflow, by all means find other paths of interest. No one has nominated you the forum police and it is self-evident that you shouldn't be 'that guy'.

Comment: Oh, I had no intention to offense you in any way. I'm sorry if I did. What I was trying to say is just that isolating problem may be great way to fix the problem. And sometimes it helps even if you can't fix the problem in other way. There is nothing wrong with asking questions, it's what SO for :)

Comment: Fair enough and I remain appreciative of your willingness to cause me to think out-of-the-box. Kind regards.

Comment: Yeah, might be my bad English. Sometimes I'm putting words in too straight-forward way, and sometimes I'm doing it in just wrong way. Being translated word-for-word from some language to English, some things become rude. It's also some kind of difference in traditions: what "OK" to say in one culture may be offensive way to saying it in other culture :)

Comment: We'd already be sharing a friendly beer if we were neighbors - worry not. A cold brew transcends all languages.  English is a very difficult language, especially for the natives :)